# Datagridview coloring rows

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, colors

I'm currently facing a problem, I am trying to color rows with a conditional IF, but I dont know why the program brings an error that cant find the column with name "Cor".
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub datagridListagem_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles datagridListagem.CellFormatting

    If datagridListagem.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Cor").Value.ToString() = "3" Then

            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green

        ElseIf datagridListagem.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Cor").Value.ToString() = "2" Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
        ElseIf datagridListagem.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Cor").Value.ToString() = "1" Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray

        End If

End Sub
```

Do you think you could help me?

Thank you

Comment: how are you binding gridview with data source.. Please check your datasource has column for datatable or property for a object datasource.. If the column name is different then use the correct one.

Comment: use indexes instead of column name, probably you column name is wrote wrong or it doesn't exist

Comment: I'm using the correct column. And I am binding data through Data Source from an Access database. The data appears when I open the program and the column is 100% named "Cor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub datagridListagem_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles datagridListagem.CellFormatting
    If datagridListagem("Cor", e.RowIndex).Value = "3" Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
    ElseIf datagridListagem("Cor", e.RowIndex).Value = "2" Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange
    ElseIf datagridListagem("Cor", e.RowIndex).Value = "1" Then
        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray
    End If
End Sub
```

Is `Cor` exist to your `DatagridView`? Check your `DatagridView` and check `Cor` if exist in the `Column`.

[image: Check this.]

Comment: It exists in my datagridview [link](http://prntscr.com/kt1qhd) check the print screen to see that it exists

Comment: I see the error of your code, You are using `DataPropertyName` but you must use is `Name` Field.

Comment: Use the `Name` not the `DataPropertyName`. `DataPropertyName` just leave it blank or none and set your `Name` as `Cor`.

Comment: Hope will resolve your issue. Your code above i think is working but your `datagridView` it seems wrong.

Comment: It worked, I'm so sorry it was a dumb rookie mistake, didnt notice I didnt change that. Thank you !!!!!

Comment: It's OK and Welcome. Happy coding.